# Python: transform float into datetime timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

How could I transform the following float:

```
9.3125
```

which corresponds to a time, into a proper Pandas timestamp in the likes of:

```
Timestamp('2017-11-13 10:00:00')
```

The float belongs to the same day, month, and year as the example timestamp above. I have been trying this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.fromtimestamp(9.3125).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

but this returns:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need [`Timedelta.ceil`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timedelta.ceil.html):

```
num = 9.3125
a = pd.Timestamp('2017-11-13')  + pd.to_timedelta(num, unit='H').ceil('H')
print (a)
2017-11-13 10:00:00
```

Comment: But 9.3125 corresponds to about 09:19, so this solution would let me lose those 19 minutes

Comment: If I use `float(num)` instead of `int(num)` I get: `ValueError: time data '2017-11-13 9.3125' doesn't match format specified`.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the answers above, I have verified that the following works for me:

```
num = 9.3125
a = pd.Timestamp('2017-11-13')  + pd.to_timedelta(num, unit='H').ceil('min')
print (a)
Timestamp('2017-11-13 09:19:00')
```